# How to bottom align and center an responsive image in a column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this layout (which is a header):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color: aqua; height: 160px;">
            <img src="logo.png" class="img-responsive logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color: blueviolet; height: 160px;"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color: aqua; height: 160px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

what i would like to achieve is:

- Align the logo to the bottom and the center
- Let the image be responsible (set width to 80% of the column)

I did this:

```
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

but it somehow dosen't work as you can see here:
https://jsfiddle.net/9kauhbhs/2/

Comment: You solution is working fine. `height` of `div` container holding image is lesser than `image`. hence you are not able to see the `bottom center` alignment. Try setting `height` to `600px` you would see it working. You could minimize `image` height or use image with appropriate dimension to see desired result.

Comment: Thanks a lot @pratikwebdev. If I do `body {margin: 20px;}` I can see it working.

Comment: Great! if you need you could try adding `max-height` element to 95% overcome the image overflow issue if you expand the screen horizontally. If screen is `medium` image overflows on `top`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..
https://jsfiddle.net/9kauhbhs/7/

```
.container{ 
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height:auto;
  margin:0 auto;
  max-height:100%;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}


<div class="col-sm-2 text-center" style="background-color: aqua; height: 160px;">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg" class="logo">
        </div>    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `left: 50%` and a margin left that is negative half of the image width.

e.g.

```
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: calc(-80% / 2); 
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwhazah7/1/)